# How do you add text to a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am making a simple NotePad app in my spare time and i have added some buttons to add some text, like the time or an essay plan etc. I am currently using the code

`textArea.setText("Text");`

But it keeps on replacing all of the text, is there anyway to just add the text to the JTextArea? I've tried

```
textArea.addText("Text");
```

and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: A few minutes spent reading the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append-java.lang.String-) and/or appropriate [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) would probably have given you the answer (not to mention actually searching the forum)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `textArea.append("text");`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `append` and `insert` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Use `textArea.append("text")`, but I recomend JTextPane for more control like color, selection, etc.